# Sending an array with Ajax to backend nests too many arrays

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, laravel

I am building an e-mail sending interface, where you can add as many recipients as you want. In the form there's a button to add new text field pairs (name and e-mail input). the multiplying JQuery looks like that:

```
var wrapper = $(".input_fields_wrap"); //Fields wrapper
var add_button = $(".add_field_button"); //Add button ID

var x = 0; //initial text box number
$(add_button).click(function (e) { //on add input button click
    e.preventDefault();
        x++; //text box increment
        $(wrapper).append(
            '<div class="form-group row multiplied">\n' +
            '    <label for="recipient_name_' + x + '" class="col-sm-1 col-form-label">Name</label>\n' +
            '        <div class="recipient_name">\n' +
            '            <input class="form-control" type="text" name="recipient_name" id="recipient_name_' + x + '">\n' +
            '        </div>\n' +
            '        <label for="recipient_email_' + x + '" class="col-sm-1 col-form-label">E-mail</label>\n' +
            '        <div class="recipient_email">\n' +
            '            <input class="form-control" type="text" name="recipient_email" id="recipient_email_' + x + '">\n' +
            '        </div>
                        <a href="#" class="ml-2 btn btn-danger remove_field">
                            <i class="fas fa-trash" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                        </a>
                    </div>'
        ); //add input box
});

$(wrapper).on("click", ".remove_field", function (e) { //user click on remove text
    e.preventDefault();
    $(this).parent('div').remove();
});
```

After form is submitted I send data to backend via ajax request. Request works fine, I send the multipled fields data like that:

```
data: {
        sender_name : $("#sender_name").val(),
        sender_email : $("#sender_email").val(),
        subject : $("#subject").val(),
        email_content: $("#email_content").val(),
        recipient_name : $('input[name="recipient_name"]').serializeArray(),
        recipient_email : $('input[name="recipient_email"]').serializeArray(),
        },
```

`

I fire it, and it gets to the backend I could be happy it's working, but the recipient_name and recipient_email variables are arrays that contains both the value and name of the element. in the following form:

```
array:2 [
  0 => array:2 [
    "name" => "recipient_name"
    "value" => "John Doe"
  ]
  1 => array:2 [
    "name" => "recipient_name"
    "value" => "Jane Doe"
  ]
]
```

But I rather want something like

```
array:2 [
  0 => "John Doe"
  1 => "Jane Doe"
]
```

With other words:

Now I access my variables like that on the backend:

```
request('recipient_name')[$key]['value'];
```

And I want it like

```
request('recipient_name')[$key];
```

Unfortunely I'm just learning ajax calls, and I'm a bit a stuck with this issue, believing there's a better solution, only I can't find it. Thanks for any help in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is just how the data is 'unpacked', you can preprocess it in PHP if you want:

```php
$myValues = array_map(function($val) { return $val['value']; }, request('recipient_name');
```

Comment: Well for my taste this solution doesn't clean up the code, but if there's no short, or easy solution for that, it's also OK for me to know it's not possible :) Thanks for help